# Android : How to implement Google like search box in my app

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on an application in which I have to fetch search text on the basis of current location and display list of searched text in a popup just like google search bar.
Is there any way that we can fetch nearest searched text on the basis of current location using Android Google Api?
Please let me know if any solution available for this.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution using G**oogle Place API** https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

In my app I want to search list of near by loaction by typing on Text Box and this tutorial https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search help a lot to me.

Thanks